# C# MVVM - мульти режимное приложение

Tags: c#, mvvm, model

Я разрабатываю приложение, в котором имеется два режима: оффлайн режим и сетевой режим. При сетевом режиме приложение взаимодействует с удалённым сервером. При оффлайн режиме, все данные сохраняются в локальной базе данных (планирую использовать какую-нибудь No-SQl базу, что то типа MongoDB).

**Вопрос:** 
Как правильно организовать логику в **Моделе**? Спроектировать более простое и универсальное решение?

**Что я имею:**
Как я предполагаю, нужна одна точка входа. Я создал класс, ApplicationDataManager, который будет подставлять нужную модель, в зависимости от режима приложения:

```
public class ApplicationDataManager
    {
        public static ApplicationMode.Modes AppMode;
        private static IModel _appInstance = null;

        private ApplicationDataManager() { }

        public static IModel Manager()
        {

        }
    }
```

Также, у меня есть модели:

```
public class RemoteInteractionModel
    {
        public void Search(object data, ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChanged, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler workerCompleated)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            worker.DoWork += SearchDoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += workerCompleated;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(data);
        }

        private void SearchDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //Здесь выполняем запрос к удалённому серверу
        }

    }

public class LocalInteractionModel
    {
        public void Search(object data, ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChanged, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler workerCompleated)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            worker.DoWork += SearchDoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += workerCompleated;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(data);
        }


        private void SearchDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //Здесь выполняем запрос к локальной базе данных
        }
    }
```

Во ViewModel, я создаю команду:

```
private DelegateCommand _search;
        public DelegateCommand Search
        {
            get
            {
                return _search ?? (_search = new DelegateCommand(SearchExecute, SearchCanExecute));
            }
        }
        private bool SearchCanExecute(object parametrs) { return true; }
        private void SearchExecute(object parametrs) { 
           ApplicationDataManager.Manager().Search(data, progress, compleate); 
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

В зависимости от источника данных меняют сервис `Repository`, который должен отвечать за сохранение, извлечение, поиск данных, т.н. `CRUD`. Вы должны создать интерфейс `IRepository`, в котором описать все нужные методы и свойства, а затем сделать две реализации этого интерфейса в зависимости от работы в онлайн/офлайн. Затем, в нужную ViewModel должны передавать нужный конструктор класса той или иной реализации `IRepository`.